# Creating Line (MultiLineString) layer out of CSV file

Tags: qgis, csv, linestring

I need to replicate a `*.qgs`-file that has 4 different layers as shown in the picture below:

[image: layers]

The layer that I am currently trying to replicate is the "**links**" layer. The information of the layer property is as below:

[image: layer information]

The attribute table of this layer looks like this:

[image: Attribute Table]

The csv file, which is the source of the layer in question, looks exactly the same with the exception of the last two columns.

I was able to display the layer visualization using the *"Points to Path"*, that comes from the "Processing Toolbox". However, I don't get the same attribute table as shown previously. In addition, it is not that straightforward as I had to manipulate the csv files beforehand.

I created a `"To_From"` column and created one csv file for `"To_From"` filled with `"to"` and one csv file for `"To_From"` filled with `"from"`. After that, I add both files using "Add>Add Layer>Add Delimited Text Layer". Subsequently, I merge the layers and create a column `"order"` with 0 for `"to"` and 1 for `"from"`. Only after this, I am able to use the "Points to Path".

I wonder if there is an alternative way for my current approach in which I am able to get the attribute table attached previously...

I am using QGIS 3.10.5-A Coruña.

Answer (score 1):

Put eye on the following workflow

1. Drag&Drop your `.csv`-file with attributes into QGIS

   [image: input]
2. Deploy a *Virtual Layer* through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` to obtain a layer with geometry, i.e. flows.

   ```sql
   SELECT *, setsrid(
                     make_line(
                               make_point("X_From","Y_From"),
                               make_point("X_To","Y_To")
                               ),
                     #here use your SRID, e.g. 25833
                     ) 
   FROM "test"
   ```
3. Get the Output

   [image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whethter I understand your question correctly!
But I would try something like the following steps:

1. Open the csv with "Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer" using "No geometry"
2. Open the File Calculator in the Attribute Table and create a new field with code similar to:
   geom_to_wkt( make_line( make_point( "xFrom" , "yFrom" ) , make_point( "xTo" , "yTo" ) ) )
3. export the table to a csv file
4. Import the new csv file with "Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Delimited Text Layer" using the new column as wkt-geometry

Good luck!